# AdMob test ads STOP working (Banner, Interstitial, Reward, Native) - Request Error 3 (Android)

Tags: android, admob

In all my android applications suddenly AdMob test ads not working. Every time AdMob returning a no fill error code 3.

I have implemented the same thing which is provided [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads).

I am also using [test unit ids](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#demo_ad_units) which are provided by AdMob.

I have already added the device as a [test device](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#add_your_test_device_programmatically).

If I perform the same implementation in a separate demo project that time test ads showing perfectly. but after that, if I implement the same thing in my live app. it is returning an error every time.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi, @VIISHRUT MAVANII ... I m also facing this issue in my app. If found any solution please share. Thank you!

Comment: Sure! @axita.savani

Comment: @VIISHRUTMAVANII - is your app live? Have you tried linking your app on admob? https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10037806?hl=en#zippy=%2Capps-listed-in-google-play-or-the-apple-app-store

Comment: @AmodGokhale Yes, the app is live. ads also coming in live app. but test ads not working during development.

Comment: @VIISHRUTMAVANII - can you check "App Readiness" section in above link and section "What to do when your app is not ready to serve ads". Also it might be silly to ask but doublecheck if AppID and BannerID both are updated for test?

Comment: Hi @AmodGokhale App ID & Banner ID both are updated with test unit id. even in demo project app test ads works perfectly but in my app test ads not working.

Comment: @axita.savani Hi, I got a solution. you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot & reaching Google [Mobile Ads SDK Technical Forum](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk). Finally got a solution.

> For Demo Test Ads

**Step 1:** Use [test ad](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#demo_ad_units) unit IDs.

**Step 2:** Setup an `app-ads.txt` file. and must include below a line

```
google.com, pub-3940256099942544, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
```

> For Live ads with Test User

**Option 1:** Add your test device in the [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#add_your_test_device_in_the_admob_ui).

**Option 2:** Add your test device [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#add_your_test_device_programmatically)